# Navigate a page from bottom to top

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navigation

I would like to navigate to a new page (from page A to page B), where the page B will move from bottom to top.

**Page A**

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, InvoiceRoutes.createInvoiceScreen.dart);
```

**InvoiceRoutes**

```
class InvoiceRoutes {
  
  static const createInvoiceScreen = "/createInvoiceScreen";
    
  static MaterialPageRoute<dynamic> _createInvoiceScreenRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => sl<OwnerInvoiceListCubit>(),
          child: BottomToTopPageRoute(page: PageB()));
    });
  }

  Route<dynamic>? getRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == createInvoiceScreen) {
      return _createInvoiceScreenRoute();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

**BottomToTopPageRoute**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomToTopPageRoute<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {
  final Widget page;

  BottomToTopPageRoute({required this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
            const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
            const end = Offset.zero;
            const curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;

            var tween =
                Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
            var offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);

            return SlideTransition(
              position: offsetAnimation,
              child: child,
            );
          },
        );
}
```

**Error**

> The argument type 'BottomToTopPageRoute' can't be assigned to
> the parameter type 'Widget?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is arising because you are using PageRouteBuilder in place of a widget. There is no need of MaterialPageRoute as you are using PageRouteBuilder.

Replace your function `_createInvoiceScreenRoute()` with

```
static BottomToTopPageRoute<dynamic> _createInvoiceScreenRoute() {
return BottomToTopPageRoute(
    page: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => sl<OwnerInvoiceListCubit>(), child: const PageB()));}
```

Hope it helps.